# Inductor Core Material

Tags: inductor, magnetics, ferrite

I need to design an Inductor of 9.717μH to be used in a DC-DC Buck chopper for current of 10A. I finished the calculations using [3C94](https://www.ferroxcube.com/upload/media/product/file/MDS/3c94.pdf) core material. When I calculate the copper loss, it is 0.35W, and the Magnetic losses are negligible since my peak flux density is 10mT.
If my losses are so low, why should I prefer 3C94 to say, a simple Iron core or very low grade low cost ferrite core?

Core - [E Core](http://ferroxcube.home.pl/prod/assets/e34149.pdf)
Frequency = 200kHz, number of turns = 10, inductor ripple = 15% of inductor current, airgap length = 0.94275 mm

I followed the procedure as in P.Krein Book on Power electronics.
[image: Refer to the last paragraph]

Comment: What core size/shape did you choose and what effective length does it have? Link to the core used. The core material spec link is good but we need the core parameters. I'm asking because with 10 amps, I doubt that the flux density will be only 10 mT. In fact, with certainty and a core that isn't as big as a small dog, B will be higher.

Comment: With a 1 mm airgap and 10 turns at 10 A =  100 AT, your H field is 100k, therefore your airgap B field is u0.H = 4pie-7*e5 = 125 mT, much more than the 10 mT you suggest, however quite a reasonable figure for that core material. Note I'm neglecting the core length as when weighted by the permeability, it's going to be small compare to the airgap. That core and that airgap computes approx the right inductance.

Comment: @Neil_UK I calculated the range B varies between - 0.1183T to 0.137T, the average value being 0.1277T. But the manufacturer provides the specific power loss due to the peak flux density right? So that will be 0.137T - 0.127T = 0.010T. That's why I said 10mT.

Comment: @STM peak flux density is 137 mT and not the difference of the magnitudes.

Comment: I initially did calculate the specific power loss using 137mT, and it came out to be 344kW/m^3. And from the core datasheet, the volume is 5590 mm^3, so the total loss is      about 1.92 W. Copper loss = ~0.356W.So net = 2.27W, against an output power=50W. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @Andyaka could you tell me why I shouldn't do it like in the Krein book? They've considered it by taking 0.05T, i.e the AC part of the flux.

Comment: (1) either the book is wrong or (2) you are misreading the book.

Comment: As you're cycling the flux round a small hysteresis loop, the losses will be much much less than cycling it between 0 and peak, or even worse +/- peak. However, the material datasheet doesn't appear to have data for the shape of the loop at that flux, so attempting to scale the losses from the more conventional peak flux may be very inaccurate.

Comment: I think the Krein book's approach is basically correct. However, where does he get those exponents from, and are they right for the core material you're using? The losses given in the material datasheet are for cycling between + and - peak flux. You might be better off doing a measurement, as the power loss will be quite sensitive to the exact field conditions. I've seen more detailed data sheets where they give the BH curves, but I don't think I've seen 15% loops on them, which is what you want.  People do design inductors, so the data must be there somewhere, ask Ferroxcube for relevant data

Comment: @Neil_UK No, the material used in the book is not the same as I'm using, I just referred to it for the procedure.I calculated it the same way and arrived at 10mT (which is 0.05T in the book), and since the core loss is seen to be negligible for this B(from 3C94 datasheet) I thought why not choose a simple Iron core?

Comment: I believe a simple iron cores tend to have very high losses at 200 kHz. Also, in bulk conductive materials such as iron/steel, inductance will be reduced because of eddy currents. Powdered cores of some kind become mandatory at higher frequencies.